# Recursively clearing a binary tree not working even though I set the individual nodes to NULL & delete them

Tags: c++, memory-management, binary-tree, linker-errors

I was trying to create a binary tree structure in cpp using the coderunner IDE on MacOS. I was supposed to have two separate files called bintree.h and bintree.cpp but I couldn't make that work due to some linker error which I couldn't fix. So I just combined both files into binarytree.h and created a client file main.cpp. The code compiles & runs successfully. However, upon checking the output, everything seems to be working except the tree_clear() function. Even after clearing the tree I can still print the cleared tree using the print() function even though I set the cleared nodes to NULL and then deleted them. Why is this happening? I'm at a dead end. Please help. Thanks in advance.

The following is my code of file binarytree.h

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H

#include <cstdlib>  // Provides NULL and size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class binary_tree_node 
{

public:

// TYPEDEF
typedef int value_type;

// CONSTRUCTOR with definition
binary_tree_node(const int& init_data = int(), binary_tree_node* init_left = NULL, binary_tree_node* init_right = NULL)
{ 
    data_field = init_data; 
    left_field = init_left; 
    right_field = init_right;
}

// MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
int &data( ) { return data_field; }
binary_tree_node* left( ) { return left_field; }
binary_tree_node* right( ) { return right_field; }
void set_data(const int &new_data) { data_field = new_data; }
void set_left(binary_tree_node* new_left) { left_field = new_left; }
void set_right(binary_tree_node* new_right) { right_field = new_right; }


// CONST MEMBER FUNCTIONS
const int& data( ) const { return data_field; }
const binary_tree_node* left( ) const { return left_field; }
const binary_tree_node* right( ) const { return right_field; }
bool is_leaf( ) const 
    { return (left_field == NULL) && (right_field == NULL); }

private:

int data_field;
binary_tree_node *left_field;
binary_tree_node *right_field;
};
#endif



////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
// IMPLEMENTATION CODE /////////////////////
// bintree.cpp         /////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
// I had to combine files bintree.h and  ///
// bintree.cpp into one file called      ///
// binarytree.h as in Mac OS the linker  ///
// generates an error during compilation ///
////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////

void print(binary_tree_node *node_ptr, int depth) 
{
    if (node_ptr != NULL) 
    {
        print(node_ptr->right( ), depth+1);
        std::cout << std::setw(4*depth) << ""; // Indent 4*depth spaces.
        std::cout << node_ptr->data( ) << std::endl;
        print(node_ptr->left( ),  depth+1);
    }
}

void tree_clear(binary_tree_node *root_ptr) 
{
    if (root_ptr != NULL) 
    {
        tree_clear( root_ptr->left( ) );
        tree_clear( root_ptr->right( ) );
        root_ptr = NULL;
        delete root_ptr;
    } 
}

//  void tree_clear(binary_tree_node *root_ptr) 
//  {
//      if (root_ptr == NULL) { return; }
//      tree_clear(root_ptr->left());
//      tree_clear(root_ptr->right());
//      root_ptr = NULL;
//      delete root_ptr;
//  }


binary_tree_node* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node* root_ptr)
{
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    binary_tree_node *l_ptr;
    binary_tree_node *r_ptr;

    if (root_ptr == NULL) return NULL;
    else
    {
        l_ptr = tree_copy( root_ptr->left( ) );
        r_ptr = tree_copy( root_ptr->right( ) );
        
        return
        new binary_tree_node( root_ptr->data( ), l_ptr, r_ptr);
    }
}
```

The following is the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "binarytree.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
//Constructor usage
binary_tree_node leftLeaf1(1), rightLeaf1(7), leftNode1(84, &leftLeaf1, NULL), rightNode1(120, NULL, &rightLeaf1), rootNode1(100, &leftNode1, &rightNode1);
cout << "Printing tree after creation through constructor:\n";
print(&rootNode1, 3);
//cout << "Print line address " << &rootNode1 << endl;

// Copying the tree
binary_tree_node* treeCopyRoot = tree_copy(&rootNode1);
cout << "\nPrinting treeCopyRoot after using tree_copy() to copy rootNode1:\n";
print(treeCopyRoot, 2);

//cout << "\nValue in root " << rootNode1.data();
//cout << "\nPrinting rootNode1:\n";


// Clearing the tree
tree_clear(&rootNode1);
cout << "\nPrinting tree after clearing through tree_clear:\n";
print(&rootNode1, 3);
```

}

Comment: put `delete root_ptr;` statement before `root_ptr = NULL;`

Comment: @lucieon I tried that before. It compiles but it gets terminated during run with this error:
Terminated due to signal: ABORT TRAP (6)main(3680,0x108017dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee95ee898: pointer being freed was not allocated
main(3680,0x108017dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Answer (score 0):

I see now. You have created the `binary_tree_node` objects in `main` on the stack. The memory locations held by those objects is bound to the `main` function. They will get released only when `main` function ends.

You see when `tree_clear` is called, the address, `&root_node1` gets copied into pointer `root_ptr`. This when assigned to `NULL`, loses access to the address `&root_node1` hence `delete` virtually does nothing as it frees memory from address location `NULL`. If you first try to do `delete root_ptr`, it gives you the error you mentioned in the comments because of reason I mentioned above.

To fix this, allocate memory on heap (use `new` to create `binary_tree_node` objects in `main`). That way the memory is not bound to anything and you can `delete` this memory from any function.